# Return not returning full data python

Tags: python, string, function, csv

I'm trying to write a python script that takes in data from a text file, gets rows between two strings, including the first string, it and use the extracted data in another function.

```
def Extracted_data(name):
    copy = False
    for data in name:
        if data.startswith ("title"):
            copy = True
        elif data.startswith ("table"):
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            return data

name = open ("file.txt").readlines()
def a():
    data = Extracted_data(name)
    print data

a()
```

This is not printing the entire data; it's printing only the first row. Sample data looks like this. It's a tab-separated text file.

```
title   A   B   F
date   23   24   12
time   1   2   5
table   y   n   y
others   rgg   grgr   grgr
```

I want

```
title   A   B   F
date   23   24   12
time   1   2   5
```

Running only the first function prints this, but when using it with the second function, I only get

```
title   A   B   F
```

How can I fix this? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points:

Firstly, `data` is the value that's being constantly updated as you iterate through `name`. That variable (unless you redefine it in your loop, which you shouldn't) will always be defined as the line you're currently reading from `name`, so returning `data` will always return only a single line.

Secondly, the way you're using your `if-elif` conditional seems a little strange. `elif` will only be evaluated if all prior `if` and `elif` statements were evaluated as false, so there's never going to be an iteration where `copy` is set to true and `data` is returned, because it's only possible for one of those lines to ever execute.

I'm not sure why the "first function" prints what you expect - assuming you mean `Extracted_data`, that's surprising, because there's no `print` function anywhere within the method.

But, this seems like it might be a better way of doing what it seems like you're after:

```
def Extracted_data(name, permitted_headers):
    result = ""
    for data in name:
        for header in permitted_headers:
            if not data is None and data.startswith(header):
                result += data
                break

    return result
```

There should be no reason to check whether the header is one that you *don't* want - just copy it to your string if it is. I've also modified this so that you pass a list of permitted headers in, just in case you wanted to reuse it to only get `title` and `date`, or any other combination.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my comments in the code:

```
def Extracted_data(name):
    copy = False  # This will false all the time you enter the function
    for data in name:
        if data.startswith ("title"):
            copy = True
        elif data.startswith ("table"):
            copy = False
        elif copy:  # May be "else:"? because you want this if everything else is false
            return data # what will you return after for loop?
```

If I do some decoration of the code:

```
def Extracted_data(name):
    copy = False
    res_data = "";  # This will build a data string
    for data in name:
        if not (data.startswith ("title")): # As you wanted nothing except title data
            copy = False             
        else:                               # It will only get "title"
            copy = True
            res_data += data                # And append it to the result
    return res_data
```

Summary:

You need to return the data after you leave for loop in a sensible way. Also remember that you are getting `copy = False` as soon as you enter the function - which probably doesn't matter now, but just a polite reminder for any future extension you do with this method.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick although there probably are better ways to solve it. As furkle stated, the if--else statement was not used properly and I added a result variable to store the temporary value.

```
   def Extracted_data(name):
    copy = False
    result = ""
    for data in name:
        if (data.startswith ("title") or data.startswith ("date") or data.startswith ("time") or data.startswith ("table")):
            copy = True
        else:
            copy = False

        if copy and not data is None:
            result += data 

    return result

name = open ("file.txt").readlines()
def a():
    data = Extracted_data(name)
    print (data)

a()
```

Comment: if data.startswith("Table") copy will be false - check the OP's code.

Comment: I agree, only in the expected output table is included. That is why included it in the list.

Comment: @RikVerbeek My bad! I'm sorry. That's my mistake. Thanks for the code. I'll try it out :)